# Deploying Web App for containers using ARM templates

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I have been trying to automate deployment of my resources to resource group on Azure. Right now I am using ARM templates and so far I was able to create App Insights and App Service Plan using a template. This is how it looks like:

```
{
   "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
   "name": "[variables('servicePlan')]",
   "kind": "linux",
   "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "tags": {
           "displayName": "BTC Push Notification Settings HostingPlan"
    },
    "sku": {
           "name": "[variables('skuNamePlan')]",
           "capacity": "[variables('skuSizePlan')]"
    },
    "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('servicePlan')]"
    }
},
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
    "name": "[variables('appInsights')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
    "location": "southcentralus",
    "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('appInsights'))]": "Resource",
            "displayName": "BTC Push Notification Settings App Insights"
     },
     "properties": {
            "applicationId": "[variables('appInsights')]"
        }
 }
```

I am having hard time creating Web App for Containers and pointing it to my docker image using ARM template. I have done it manually and it worked, likewise I did it through `azure-cli` like this `az webapp create --resource-group ExampleGroupAlpina --plan myAppServicePlan --name DockerContainer --deployment-container-image-name this-is-my-image/sample-docker` and this worked as well. I would appreciate if anyone could suggest creating this Web App for Containers using ARM Template.

Comment: You can accept it If possible and the answer is correct so that the answer can help others who are looking for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following ARM template worked for me.

- It allows to specify the authentication details of a private Azure Container Registry.
- Also make sure the docker image name follows this pattern: `_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_-on.azurecr.io/_MY_NAMESPACE_/_MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_:latest`

I run the `az` command like this:

```
az group deployment create \
  --name "deployAzureApp" \
  --resource-group <MY_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> \
  --template-file <MY_ARM_JSON_TEMPLATE>.json  --verbose --debug
```

Here's the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) JSON template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_APP_NAME_"
    },
    "dockerImageName": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_-on.azurecr.io/_MY_NAMESPACE_/_MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_:latest"
    },
    "dockerRegistryUrl": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "https://_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_-on.azurecr.io"
    },
    "dockerRegistryUsername": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_"
    },
    "dockerRegistryPassword": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_PSW_"
    },
    "servicePlanName": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_SERVICE_PLAN_NAME_"
    },
    "appLocation": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGION_"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "kind": "app,linux,container",
      "location": "[parameters('appLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[concat('DOCKER|', parameters('dockerImageName'))]",
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE",
              "value": "false"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryUrl')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryUsername')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryPassword')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('servicePlanName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me anymore, I get "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value." when submitting something like:
"linuxFxVersion": "username.azurecr.io/namespace/imagename:latest"

Comment: Did you remember the `DOCKER|` in front of the image repo details? Still works as far as I can see.

Comment: Why there is -on in registry url https://_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_-on.azurecr.io

Comment: @zolty13 that's a placeholder for the name of the private docker registry

Answer (score 11):

For me none of these other answers worked. With the assistance of Azure support and these other answers I came up with the following template, that succesfully creates an app service plan with an Linux App Service for Containers running a custom Docker image from Azure Container Repository:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environment":{
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location (region) for all resources."
      }
    },   
    "appServiceSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "B1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SKU of App Service Plan "
      }
    },
    "dockerImageName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_.azurecr.io/_MY_NAMESPACE_/_MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_:_TAG_"
    },
    "dockerRegistryUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_.azurecr.io"
    },
    "dockerRegistryUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_USERNAME_"
    },
    "dockerRegistryPassword": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "_MY_REGISTRY_PSW_"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "name": "projectname-",
    "webAppPortalName": "[concat(variables('name'), parameters('environment'), '-webapp')]",
    "appServicePlanName": "[concat(variables('name'), parameters('environment'),'-hosting')]",
  "resources": [       
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "kind": "linux",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "comments": "This app service plan is used for the web app and slots.",
      "properties": {
        "reserved": true
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('appServiceSku')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webAppPortalName')]",
      "kind": "app,linux,container",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webAppPortalName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[concat('DOCKER|', parameters('dockerImageName'))]",
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE",
              "value": "false"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryUrl')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryUsername')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD",
              "value": "[parameters('dockerRegistryPassword')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`_artifactsLocation` and `_artifactsLocationSasToken` do not need values, but somehow they need to be included. The main difference to other answers is the inclusion of the `reserved` attribute in the `properties` for the App Service Plan.

Hopefully this saves some of the headache this created for me!

Comment: I was able to deploy without needing `_artifactsLocation`, apparently this field is only required if you work with linked templates. Also `linuxFxVersion` is generated automatically by the *Deploy Azure App Service* task so no need to add that. This results in the `DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME` app setting being set to the value of `linuxFxVersion`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me anymore, I get "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value." when submitting something like:
"linuxFxVersion": "username.azurecr.io/namespace/imagename:latest"

Answer (score 3):

About Azure Web App for Container, actually, there is just one point different with Azure Web App in the template. The point is the kind type.

Azure Web App:

```
"kind": "app"
```

Azure Web App for Container:

```
"kind": "app,linux,container",
```

So, you can create the Azure Web App for Container using template just setting up the kind with `app,linux,container`.

**Update**

I do the test and find out that the website kind is not the most important. The key is the property of the website:

```
"siteConfig": {
                    "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|nginx"
                },
```

And the template will like below and it does a good job.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Base name of the resource such as web app name and app service plan "
            },
            "minLength": 2
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "S1",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The SKU of App Service Plan "
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "webAppPortalName": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '-webapp')]",
        "appServicePlanName": "[concat('AppServicePlan-', parameters('webAppName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "kind": "linux",
            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "comments": "This app service plan is used for the web app and slots.",
            "properties": {},
            "dependsOn": [],
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "name": "[variables('webAppPortalName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "comments": "This is the web app, also the default 'nameless' slot.",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appCommandLine": "",
                    "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|nginx"
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however, it is not going to work for docker, unless you add `"linuxFxVersion": "[concat('DOCKER|', parameters('dockerCustomImageName'))]"` to properties of your web app. Moreover, you have to specify other properties like `password`, `username`,`url`.

Comment: @RustamUmarov Yeah, I did the test and update the answer.

Comment: Please, edit `"linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|nginx"` to `"linuxFxVersion": "[concat('DOCKER|', parameters('dockerCustomImageName'))]"`

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT how to do this when pulling the docker image from a private Azure Container Registry? How is the JSON/ARM syntax to provide the authentication details to the Azure Container Registry?

Answer (score 2):

For what I observed, the **linuxFxVersion** problem depends on the App Service Plan where the Web App is hosted. What helped me was to set the **reserved** property on the properties object of App Service Plan resource to **true**.

What [Microsoft doumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2016-09-01/serverfarms#AppServicePlanProperties) says about the **reserved** setting:

> If Linux app service plan true, false otherwise.

It says nothing about its default value, but from what I observed its **false**.

This is how my App Service Plan resource ARM template looks like.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
  "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuName')]",
    "tier": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuTier')]",
    "size": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuSize')]",
    "family": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuFamily')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuCapacity')]"
  },
  "kind": "linux",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
    "reserved": true
  }
}
```

Comment: it is well known problem. Often is is forgotten that reserver is necessary. If you want to use windows containers linuxFxVersion is not necessary. Instead you may need windowsFxVersion

Answer (score 0):

The above template doesn't work now and will show the following logs-

```
[error]BadRequest: {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "01007",
        "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters": [
          "LinuxFxVersion"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

To fix this, We can make it 2 steps deployment process as mentioned in the following blog
[Updated Solution](https://blog.ehn.nu/2019/01/deploy-azure-web-app-for-containers-with-arm-and-azure-devops/)